# Downloading a json file (from json-server) as a txt or json or csv file, in an Angular app

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, json-server

I have installed the `json-server` in my Angular app which enables me to save a form (filled by the user) via a fake json API into a json file:

```
{
  "extracts": [
    {
      "contentName": "xxx",
      "contentType": "xxx",
      "contentToStore": "xxx",
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I can also see the results at my `http://localhost:3000/extracts`

In my `html` template, my form is submitted:

```
<form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitExtractions(postForm.value)">
```

In the corresponding component, I have written this code:

```
onSubmitExtractions(postData: Post) {
    
    this
      .dbService
      .submitExtractions(postData)
      .subscribe(
        postData => {
          this.jsonPosts.push(postData);
        }
    );
    
    this
      .dbService
      .downloadExtractions(postData);
}
```

The first snippet writes to the json file, with this code in the service script:

```
submitExtractions(post: Post): Observable<Post> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Post>(this.apiUrl, post, httpOptions);
}
```

This works fine and I get the results in a json file (fake json server database) and the second snippet is supposed to download this file whose code in the service script is this:

```
downloadExtractions(post: Post) {

    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(post, null, 2)], { type: 'application/json' });

    if (blob) {
      this.downloaded = 'The blob contains ' + blob.size + ' byte!';
    } else {
      this.downloaded = 'The download failed!';
    }
}
```

What am I missing in ths code in order to actually download the json content? How do I download this content as a **csv** or **json** or even a **text** file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this solution. It is using the same blob just with some constant data.

in html

```
<a [href]="fileUrl" download="file.txt">DownloadFile</a>
```

in component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  fileUrl;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const data = 'some text';
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

    this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }

}
```

For reference, please visit:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-file-download-text-file?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Trouble Thank you. This is helpful. What I do not understand is `fileUrl`. What url is this exactly? When I try your code in my method, the downloaded file contains the content of my `index.html`. Is `fileUrl` supposed to be my `apiUrl` which is the url for the json file created in my app by the `json-server`?

Comment: Ok, fileUrl is just a handler to call DOMSanitizer here. window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) is creating a new url with reference to the current url your application is at and adding object (here blob) to that url.
In the end, fileUrl bypasses your current security and passes this url to DOM which in turn download a file for you. Hope it make some sense and you can use console.log() to check variations. 

If  you want to get data from api, you can get that to create blob and then pass that blob here to download.